# Using binomial distribution to find probability range

Tags: probability

If the probability that a moose has three antlers is z and I have 500 moose, I want to find the probability that more than 8 moose have three antlers. Since these are independent events, I want to use the binomial distribution, so that 500C8 * (z)^8 * (1 - z)^500-8 which expands to `500!/(500-8)!8! * (z)^8 * (1 - z)^492`

Is this correct?

Comment: If $X\sim Bin(500,z)$ then $X$ is models the numbers of mooses with three antlers, if we count how many of 500 random mooses have three antlers where the probability of each moose having three antlers is z. Your question is then answered by finding $P(X > 8)$.

Comment: Let $X$ be the number of three-antlered moose. On the (dubious) assumption of independence, you know how to compute $\Pr(X=k)$. You want the probability of more than $8$, so you want $\Pr(X=9)+\Pr(X=10)+\cdots+\Pr(X=500)$. A lot of calculation! It is easier to find the probability $p$ is $\le 8$. This is $\Pr(X=0)+\cdots+\Pr(X=8)$. Then our required probability is $1-p$.

Answer (score 3):

That is the correct expression for *exactly* 8 moose having three antlers. You want "more than". So, generally, we have the probability that $k$ moose have three antlers is:

$$P(n = k) = \binom{500}{k}z^k(1-z)^{500-k}$$

We just need to sum that:

$$P(n \gt 8) = \sum_{k=9}^{500}P(n=k) = \sum_{k=9}^{500}\binom{500}{k}z^k(1-z)^{500-k}$$

Comment: It will, of course be easier to calculate using the complement. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(N>8) &=1-\mathsf P(N\leq 8) \\ &= 1 -\sum_{k=0}^8 \dbinom{500}{k} z^k (1-z)^{500-k}\end{align}$$